# I need the compliment of text file containing "ATGC"

Tags: php, string

I have a text file containing string formed by only four type of characters A,T,G,C 
 for example-

```
TGTGGCCAAGAAAACAGGAAAAGAGGGCGGACCGAAAATCATGGTTGCCGGACACCTGGA
CGAAGTAGGATTCATGATCACAAGCATTGATGACAAAGGCTTCCTCCGCTTCCAGACGGT
CGGTGGCTGGTGGTCACAGGTTATGCTTGCCCAGCGTGTCACCATTGTAACTAGCAAAGG
```

now I need the compliment of above text file using PHP

and compliment of

```
A is T, 
T is A,
G is C,
C is G.
```

MY CODE IS

```
$str = TGTGGCCAA;

$str =str_replace("A","T",$str);
$str =str_replace("T","A",$str);
$str =str_replace("G","C",$str);
$str =str_replace("C","G",$str);

echo"$str";
```

Comment: What would be your expected output? Have you tried something?

Comment: The first premise here is that you need to try writing the code yourself and then people will help you solve your problems. Show what you've got so far.

Comment: ok forget about text file for some time, first let suppose my input string is"TGTGGCCAA"  then output will be "ACACCGGTT"

Comment: You want to look at the [strtr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) function with replace_pairs

Comment: Check this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e4674639df04743fae5b48d156f6d12c253b54be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `strtr` function, see the code below (I've just make yout input string shorter):

```
<?php

$str = 'TGTGGCCAAGAAAACAGGAAAAGAGGGCGGACCG';  
echo strtr($str, array('A' => 'T', 'T' => 'A', 'G' => 'C', 'C' => 'G'));
// out: ACACCGGTTCTTTTGTCCTTTTCTCCCGCCTGGC

?>
```

Comment: Yes, use this method.

Comment: ... or shorter
`echo strtr($str, 'ATGC', 'TACG');`